# ng boostrap + angular4: dynamical html modal content loading

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have the following architecture:

```
.
├── companies.component.ts
├── companies.html
├── companies.service.ts
└── components
    └── modal
        ├── modal.component.html
        └── modal.component.ts
```

My modal component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'service-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html'
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  public modalHeader: string;
  public modalContent: string;

  constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
  }

  public closeModal() {
    this.activeModal.close();
  }
}
```

And I use it from my `companies.component.ts` like this:

```
const activeModal = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent, { size: 'lg' });
activeModal.componentInstance.modalHeader = 'Create company';
activeModal.componentInstance.modalContent = 'company form';
```

I would like to use the modal component to create company OR user entities. Is it a good practice to bind html form to the modalContent? Is there an other way to do so? Should I create two different modal components (one for user, one for company)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might re-use your modal in other places. So you should put this component in a 'shared' folder.

Then you have multiple solutions :

1. With ng-content. You create your modal component or use bootstrap's.

> ```
> <my-modal>
>     <my-comp-to-create-companies>
>     </my-comp-to-create-companies>
> </my-modal>
> <my-modal>
>     <my-comp-to-edit-companies></my-comp-to-edit-companies>
> </my-modal>
> ```

You might be able to merge edit/create components, because the form might have the same properties.

2. Dynamic Component Loader : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader